# Android: Compilation error on my if else statement

Tags: android, if-statement

The Eclispe complier show me the error sntax on my else statements on my else if. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? thanks!

**code**

```
//click on one of chapters
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {

            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Choose Chapter 1
            if (item.equalsIgnoreCase("I. The Global Business Environment")); {
            //go to chapter 1
            startActivity(new Intent(ChaptersActivity.this, Chapter1Activity.class));
            } else if (item.equalsIgnoreCase("II. Information Systems")); {
                //go to chapter 2
                startActivity(new Intent(ChaptersActivity.this, Chapter2Activity.class));
            }

          //Choose Chapter 3
            else if (item.equalsIgnoreCase("III. Operations Management"));
            {
                //go to chapter 3
                startActivity(new Intent(ChaptersActivity.this, Chapter3Activity.class));
            }

          //Choose Chapter 4
            else if (item.equalsIgnoreCase("IV. Marketing"));
            {
                //go to chapter 4
                startActivity(new Intent(ChaptersActivity.this, Chapter4Activity.class));
            }

          //Choose Chapter 5
            else if (item.equalsIgnoreCase("V. Managing Human Capital"));
            {
                //go to chapter 5
                startActivity(new Intent(ChaptersActivity.this, Chapter5Activity.class));
            }

          //Choose Chapter 6
            else if (item.equalsIgnoreCase("VI. Preparing for the Examination"));
            {
                //go to chapter 6
                startActivity(new Intent(ChaptersActivity.this, Chapter6Activity.class));
            }
        }
    });
```

They display error sntax on 'else' codes words, any ideas?

Comment: a better way to do this is to use id attribute on your views then call view.getId() and put into a switch statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `semicolon` at the end of your if conditions:

```
if (item.equalsIgnoreCase("I. The Global Business Environment")); {
```

That ends the if statement, the { starts a fresh block, then else shows up out of nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

The `;` shows up in every `if-else` condition statement. You're better remove them out and try to Build it again :)